# Event only fired after first click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of categorie. When I click on some category to fire an AJAX request the first time the request is not sent. When i click a second time it works great. Here is my code

```
<?php foreach($this->category as $value) { ?>
  <li data-cid=<?= $value['cat_id']?> class="cid">
    <a href="http://localhost/mvc/viewbycat/index/<?= $value['cat_id'] ?>">
      <?= $value['cat_name']?>
    </a>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var catid;
  var count = 0;

  $('li.cid').click(function (e) {
    count = 0;
    var limit = 6;
    var offset = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main").empty();
    catid = $(this).attr('data-cid');
    displayRecords1(limit, offset, catid);
  });
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please don't edit and add code to the users question @guradio, he has a syntax error, don't fix it as it confuses people, clean the formatting but don't fix errors within the questioners code, rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

You had a `Unexpected end of input` error because you were missing `});`,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var catid,
      count = 0;
  $('li.cid').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var limit = 6,
        offset = 0,
        count = 0;

    $("#main").empty();

    catid = $(this).attr('data-cid');

    displayRecords1(limit, offset, catid);
  });
});
```

Change,

```
<li data-cid=<?= $value['cat_id']?> class="cid">
```

To

```
/** Note the double quotes. **/
<li data-cid="<?= $value['cat_id']?>" class="cid">
```

- Avoid using short tags in PHP as they might be disabled on your server.
- Always check the console for JavaScript errors.
- Try and initialise all your variables together at the start to prevent confusion.

**Reading Material**

[Opening Console in Different Browsers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

[PHP Short Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

[JavaScript Syntax Checker](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) - For quick checking of your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    var catid;
    var count=0;

    $('li.cid').click(function (e) {
        count=0;
        var limit= 6;
        var offset = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#main").empty();
        catid = $(this).attr('data-cid');

        displayRecords1(limit, offset, catid);
    });
}); // This here
```

Comment: this is just the part of code of document ready at the i have the right end. Thnak you

Comment: It is not the reason to work from second click as i sad i close document.ready i have more code